# I'm failing to set up a wireless Access Point (AP)

Tags: linux-kernel, wifi

I'm trying to get [this card](http://www.embeddedworks.net/pdetail.php?mn=wlan&mid=mwlan2502&prod=wlan373) to be an access point, and am failing. I tried various Ubuntu releases, and checked on both ARM and i386. The kernel version I used is 2.6.35, and there is no Network Manager.

Here's the log entries on `/var/log/syslog` when I connect the device:

```
May 27 10:56:46 vab kernel: usb wakeup is here
May 27 10:56:46 vab kernel: ehci_fsl_bus_resume, Host 1
May 27 10:56:46 vab kernel: usb 2-1.2: new high speed USB device using fsl-ehci and address 8
May 27 10:56:47 vab kernel: usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=9271
May 27 10:56:47 vab kernel: usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=48
May 27 10:56:47 vab kernel: usb 2-1.2: Product: WLAN 
May 27 10:56:47 vab kernel: usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: MVA1020
May 27 10:56:47 vab kernel: usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 12345
May 27 10:56:47 vab kernel: usb 2-1.2: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ar9271.fw, size: 51312
May 27 10:56:49 vab kernel: ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x10
May 27 10:56:49 vab kernel: ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
May 27 10:56:49 vab kernel: ath: Country alpha2 being used: CO
May 27 10:56:49 vab kernel: ath: Regpair used: 0x10
May 27 10:56:49 vab kernel: Registered led device: ath9k-phy4::radio
May 27 10:56:49 vab kernel: Registered led device: ath9k-phy4::assoc
May 27 10:56:49 vab kernel: Registered led device: ath9k-phy4::tx
May 27 10:56:49 vab kernel: Registered led device: ath9k-phy4::rx
May 27 10:56:49 vab kernel: usb 2-1.2: ath9k_htc: USB layer initialized
```

**`hostapd`** config file:

```
$ cat config
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=test
channel=1
```

And running it:

```
$ sudo hostapd conf 
Configuration file: conf
Failed to set interface wlan0 to master mode.
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
ELOOP: remaining socket: sock=5 eloop_data=0xa4a38 user_data=(nil) handler=0x3d2f8
```

Output of `iw list`:

```
Wiphy phy4
    Band 1:
        Capabilities: 0x104e
            HT20/HT40
            SM Power Save disabled
            RX HT40 SGI
            No RX STBC
            Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
            DSSS/CCK HT40
        Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
        Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
        HT TX/RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (27.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (27.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (27.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (27.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (27.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (27.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (27.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (27.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (27.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (27.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (27.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (disabled)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (disabled)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (disabled)
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
    max # scan SSIDs: 4
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * monitor
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * new_beacon
         * new_station
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * Unknown command (55)
         * Unknown command (57)
         * Unknown command (59)
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * Unknown command (65)
         * connect
         * disconnect
```

For this to work, I expect to see **AP** listed in `Supported interface modes` on that output (as it does when I connect it on my Debian 7.0+ desktop, which has Network Manager running).

Comment: Have you checked if your wifi controller requires a proprietary firmware? Many do, some only for some features such as acting as an AP.

Comment: It does, and I assumed it was successfully loaded looking at `ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ar9271.fw, size: 51312`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, the issue was that my kernel was too old. I made use of the [compat-wireless tools](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Download/stable/), which backports new wireless drivers to old kernels. I got the latest version showed on that page (3.6.x), followed the instructions, and it works... and I am happy.